# Problems entering a boolean matrix with checkboxInput's

Tags: r, shiny

Being quite new to programming in Shiny I ean across a problem I cannot solve, no matter how much I search in the net.

I want the user to enter a boolen matrix through checkboxInput's. However, when I try to copy the values into the matrix, it apparently does not change. I tried both, `reactive()` and `observeEvent()`, without success.

Here is some example code:

```
library(shiny)
library(markdown)
library(relations)

prbm <- matrix (c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE), 2, 2)

# Define UI ----
ui <- navbarPage("",
         tabPanel("Your Turn",
                  fluidRow(column(5, "Enter your Relation!")),
                  fluidRow(column(1,
                        checkboxInput("pr1", "(1, 1)", prbm[1,1]),
                        checkboxInput("pr2", "(1, 2)", prbm[1,2])),
                     column(1,
                        checkboxInput("pr3", "(2, 1)", prbm[2,1]),
                        checkboxInput("pr4", "(2, 2)", prbm[2,2])),
                     column(10, uiOutput("value"))
                  )
                  )
         )

# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  reactive(prbm[2,2] <- input$pr4)
  reactive(prbm[2,1] <- input$pr3)
  observeEvent(input$pr2, prbm[1,2] <- input$pr2)
  observeEvent(input$pr1, prbm[1,1] <- input$pr1)
  output$value <- renderTable(prbm, colnames=FALSE)
}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I also tried global assignments without success. The `observeEvent()` function is executed (I tested that with some `cat()`to `stderr`.Whatever I click in the checkboxes, nothing changes in the printed matrix.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance,
   Cord

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that the `renderTable` never gets called once you changed the value of `pbrm`. To do so you can use `reactiveValues` combined with `observeevent` as shown below:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
        Rprbm <- reactiveValues(val=prbm)
        # reactive(Rprbm$val[2,2] <- input$pr4)
        # reactive(Rprbm$val[2,1] <- input$pr3)

        observeEvent(input$pr2, Rprbm$val[1,2] <- input$pr2)
        observeEvent(input$pr1, Rprbm$val[1,1] <- input$pr1)
        observeEvent(input$pr3, Rprbm$val[2,1] <- input$pr3)
        observeEvent(input$pr4, Rprbm$val[2,2] <- input$pr4)
        output$value <- renderTable(Rprbm$val, colnames=FALSE)
      }
```

Another option that minimizes the code you write would be using `reactive` as shown below:

```
   server <- function(input, output) {
        Tab <- reactive({
          matrix(c(input$pr1, input$pr2, input$pr3, input$pr4), 2,2) 
        })

        output$value <- renderTable(Tab(), colnames=FALSE)
      }
```